# RegisterForContextMenu seems to have no effect

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

From what I've been able to gather from google, calling RegisterForContextMenu on a view should be all I have to do if I want OnCreateContextMenu to be called when I long click on said view. This does not happen.

The funny thing is, if I pass in View instead of gameList in the code below, the context menu appears if I long click at an empty portion of the main view. Long clicking on the list (which is a subview) still has no result.

I also tried registering a ItemLongClick event listener on the ListView, this does not get called either :/

The GameList fragment is run inside a viewpager.

```
using Android.Views;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;

using Android.Support.V4.App;

using Models = Boardwar.Common.Models;
using Boardwar.AndroidClient.Adapters;


namespace Boardwar.AndroidClient.Fragments {
    public class GameList : Fragment {
        GamesAdapter GamesAdapter;


        public GameList () {
        }

        public GameList (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership jni) : base(handle, jni) {
        }


        public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle bundle) {
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.GameList, parent, false);
        }

        public override void OnActivityCreated (Bundle p0) {
            base.OnActivityCreated(p0);

            var mainActivity = Activity as MainActivity;

            var gameList = View.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.game_list);

            GamesAdapter = new GamesAdapter(mainActivity);
            gameList.Adapter = GamesAdapter;
            mainActivity.GamesAdapter = GamesAdapter;

            RegisterForContextMenu(gameList);

            View.FindViewById(Resource.Id.new_game_button).Click += (sender, e) => {
                mainActivity.ReplaceChildFragments(typeof(NewGame));
            };
        }

        public override void OnCreateContextMenu (IContextMenu menu, View view, IContextMenuContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            base.OnCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
            menu.Add(Resource.String.remove_finished_games);
        }

        public override bool OnContextItemSelected (IMenuItem item) {
            MainActivity.Client.RemoveFinishedGames();
            return true;
        }

        public override void OnResume () {
            base.OnResume();
            GamesAdapter.UpdateList();
        }

        public override void OnDestroyView () {
            base.OnDestroyView();
            (Activity as MainActivity).GamesAdapter = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you throw out Xamarin or whatever you're using and try your code in a conventional setting?  I can tell you that registerForContextMenu(list) works the way you're expecting it to with a regular setup.  Bear in mind, I don't expect you to stop using C#, but doing so for the sake of one test will at least help you identify the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I was registering ClickHandlers on the actual list-items, instead of a global ClickHandler on the actual list-view. This would block the click event from propegating to the list-view, which is why the context menu wouldn't appear.

Comment: can you move this along with your question because this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The question was why OnCreateContextMenu isn't called. It wasn't called because I handled all click events at each item in the list, instead of the list itself. The list doesn't receive click events, therefore it will never know when a long click happens, and it can't create the context menu...